# SSD and file recovery (on Windows 8)

Tags: ssd, data-recovery, windows-8, file-recovery, trim

Typical commercial "file recovery tools" are not usefull on modern SSDs, because the recovered file (if any) appears empty.

Windows 8 sends the TRIM command to the SSD when a file gets deleted from trash. Similarly the new "disk optimizer" is supposed to run a TRIM on the drive SSD on monthly schedule (instead of the old defrag on hdd).

**My question:** is it possible to avoid the instant-TRIM, but keep the monthly-TRIM, so that the "file recovery" works again?

In fact, does turning off `[disabledeletenotify]`[1](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc785435.aspx) fully disable it system wide including both instant+monthly TRIM?

Comment: The answer to this question depends if you have shadow copy enabled or not.

Comment: Wow, you are right, but lets asume "shadow copy" is disabled -- because normally it shouldn't cover the whole disk (and in SSD space is scarce).

Answer (score 0):

Would [this forum post](http://forum.corsair.com/v3/showthread.php?t=86403) help?

According to that thread, you can disable TRIM by issuing the command:

```
fsutil behavior set disabledeletenotify 1
```

And you can re-enable it by this means:

```
fsutil behavior set disabledeletenotify 0
```

If you want to query the current status of TRIM:

```
fsutil behavior query disabledeletenotify
```

And the results of that query can be explained thusly:

```
DisableDeleteNotify = 1 (Windows TRIM commands are disabled)
DisableDeleteNotify = 0 (Windows TRIM commands are enabled)
```

You could create two batch/cmd scripts, one to enable and the other to disable TRIM.

Of course, you could always try some of [these solutions](http://www.cso.com.au/article/443119/review_file_recovery_tools/).

Comment: Well, enabling/disabling requires full restart of windows, so this is not really an automatic solution... sorry.

Comment: There likely isn't an automatic solution if you want to toggle TRIM on/off

Comment: Like Ramhound says, anything that deals with turning off OS file system features usually requires a restart of sorts.